# Change iframe source multiple times

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

I made an iFrame and would like to change it's source when it's load to next of 10 different sources:

It would look like this:

iframe loaded => change to example.com => iframe loaded => change to example1.com => iframe loaded => change to example2.com...

Is there any way to do this? ...
I've tried a lot of stuff and stuck on something like this: (of course does not work at all)

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe onload="srca('http://www.com', 'a')" src="http://www.example.com"> </iframe>
<script>
function srca (src, load){

document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = src
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src)
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = load 
}

function a(){
srca('http://js.do', 'b')
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem like this: **[working jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/042zg96h/1/)**

The javascript part is the following:

```
urls = ['http://www.example.com', 'http://www.com', 'http://js.do'];
position = 0;
element = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
element.onload = frameLoaded;
next();  /* i.e. load the first */

function next() {
    if (urls.length > position) {
        element.src = urls[position];
        position += 1;
    }
}

function frameLoaded() {
    setTimeout(next, 4000);
}
```

**I got [your code working.](http://jsfiddle.net/1v7tL8pp/) The problems were:**

- hard to read :-P
- when you want pass around a named function, use it’s name, not a string of it, i.e.:

  - `blabla.onload = a`
  - `blabla.onload = 'a'` is wrong
- the `onload` event fired before the script, i.e. the function you call is not defined yet

  - this is a common issue
  - I fixed it by putting the script part before the `<iframe>`
  - the code of my solution is supposed to be executed by `body.onload` (jsfiddle does that)

Comment: Changes nothing.. =.= My whole idea is bad, I wrote about it.