# iFrame change source multiple times

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

I made an iFrame and would like to change it's source when it's load to next of 10 different sources:

It would look like this:

iframe loaded => change to example.com => iframe loaded => change to example1.com => iframe loaded => change to example2.com...

Is there any way to do this? ... I'm stuck on this and have no idea what can i do:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.example.com"> </iframe>
<script>   
var links = [
"http://www.js.com", 
"http://example.com", 
"http://example1.com"];

alert(links[2])

function srca (){
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = links[0]
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change iframe source multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561481/change-iframe-source-multiple-times)

Comment: Why did you ask this twice?

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, you just forgot to hook into some kind of event (like onload)..
Just to get you started, here ya go:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>   
var links = [ 'http://www.js.com'
            , 'http://example.com' 
            , 'http://example1.com'
            ]
,  lnkCnt = 0
;
function srca(){
   links.length > lnkCnt && (
     document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = links[lnkCnt++]
   );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="about:blank" onload="setTimeout(srca, 2000);"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```